# Number of times an event occurs per year depending on start date and frequency (excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to develop a formula in MS Excel that will give me the number of occurrences a task will happen in a year (or month), based on a start date, frequency and schedule in a table. I am looking to produce a table like the following (assuming the start date is 01/01/YR1):

[image: desired results]

I'm open to VBA suggestions also.

The minimum frequency is completing the task every week. Not taking into account daily tasks here. The data is held in a table. I calculated the 'times per year' using :

```
=IF([@Schedule]="Months",(12/[@Frequency]), IF([@Schedule]="Weeks",(52/[@Frequency]),IF([@Schedule]="Years",1/[@Frequency],0)))
```

I may look to take this onto a monthly schedule also, i.e. number of occurrences for each month across 5 years. It would also be useful to specify an overall end date for when the tasks would stop. (e.g. sometimes it would be year 3, sometimes year 5)

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: suc6 while developing! i am (together with more people het on SO)  waiting for you code questions....... 

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(D$2=1,ROUND(D$2*$C3-0.45,0),ROUND(D$2*$C3-0.45,0)-SUM($D3:OFFSET($C3,0,D$2-1)))
```

[image: Frequency Table]

The formula is dragable so just place it in D3 then drag across then down. Also note the change in format of the table so the year numbers are usable in the calculations.

Note: I would suggest that the value the 5th year of the 2.5 year frequency is incorrect.
In the 3rd year you would do it and have a half year remaining. Then add that to years 4 & 5 and you get 2.5 time to do it again.

Comment: thank you, this worked. I had to slightly reformat to be able to use with data table references (offset did not like them). And good spot with the 2.5years... thats one of the reasons why we use formulas!